# Is there any way to automate scan QR code by Appium for IOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, automation, appium, qr-code

I have an application runs in Android and IOS but one of the main functionalities depends on scan QR code through mobile camera. So is there any way to do this with Appium?

Comment: I have added solution which will work for both IOS and android as its not using any  native function of appium to read QR. we are just capturing screen with help of Appium. Please check it. I would say to accept it as answer and upvote. This is good question and will help SO community and the people who will face same problem in future.

Comment: The one way to automate qr code scanning is to use some mechanical fixture (i.e adjust your mobile device camera in front of QR code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think so appium have native functionality to do this. We can use [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) external library to achieve it.

`Zxing` is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java, with ports to other languages. One supported 2D format is the QR code.

> An easy solution is to take a screenshot from the device screen, get
> the points (width and height) from the element on the device, and crop
> the image to the element size, so you have an image with just the QR
> code. Now, you can use Zxing to read the QR code content.

**1. Add `Zxing` maven dependency to `Pom.xml`**

```
<dependency>

    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>

    <version>3.3.0</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>

    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>

    <version>3.3.0</version>

</dependency>
```

**2. Get QR code image from App using Appium**

```
private BufferedImage generateImage( MobileElement element, File screenshot) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage fullImage = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

    Point imageLocation = element.getLocation();



    int qrCodeImageWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();

    int qrCodeImageHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();



    int pointXPosition = imageLocation.getX();

    int pointYPosition = imageLocation.getY();



    BufferedImage qrCodeImage = fullImage.getSubimage(pointXPosition, pointYPosition, qrCodeImageWidth, qrCodeImageHeight);

    ImageIO.write(qrCodeImage, "png", screenshot);



    return qrCodeImage;

}
```

**3. Decode QR code from Image generated using above function**

```
private static String decodeQRCode(BufferedImage qrCodeImage) throws NotFoundException {
        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(qrCodeImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);
        return result.getText();
    }
```

**4. How to utilise generateImage() and  readQRCode()**

```
public void readQRCode() throws IOException, NotFoundException {

   MobileElement qrCodeElement = driver.findElement(By.id("com.eliasnogueira.qr_code:id/qrcode"));

   File screenshot = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);



   String content = decodeQRCode(generateImage(qrCodeElement, screenshot));

   System.out.println("content = " + content);

}
```

So in `content` is the information have fetched from QR code.

**Reference:** step by step guide is [here](https://qa-genes.blogspot.com/2021/12/and-verify-qr-code-with-zxing-and.html) and sample code is [here](https://github.com/eliasnogueira/appium-read-qrcode?files=1)

Comment: this is really good solution ..but in our case for ecom application, we have to scan the QR code(For automating it should be came from some img file as we can not put the hard copy of QR code in front the camera for all the time and feed to camera which is already on) and respective items should be displayed on the screen..

Comment: @SacTan in this case you can store expected/baseline result i.e. you have to scan your testing QR code and save that information behind QR code and Now you have expected/baseline result. Actual result, now you can scan same testing QR code with above code and validate it with expected/baseline result. I have used this approach where we have complex system (in my case google map) so we can save baseline/expected result from AUT and then compare it with actual results.